# Making mobile optimised forms

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have made a form to take users name, it is working well on desktop but it appears too small on mobile device though I made it using bootstrap.

```
<form method="post" id="mainform">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="user_name"
                       placeholder="Eg. John Doe"
                       class="form-control"
                       required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If my answer doesn't help you, you might want to provide more of your surrounding html and which version of bootstrap you're using, so people who regularly use bootstrap may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: write your own css rule with whatever media query you need to change the layout on devices with less width. We normally do it this way: Resize your browser window down until you find the spot where it doesn't look nice anymore (or doesn't look the way you want anymore), then find the exact pixel width by resizing the browser window pixel by pixel, then write a media query for that width to fix it.

---

I would suggest using the the more semantical fieldset tag in place of your div.form-group (if there are other inputs in your real html). Also your html is definitely over-polluted with unneccessary tags and classes (and missing a label). Clean html could look like this:

```
<form method="post" id="mainform"><label for="input-user_name">Name:</label><input id="input-user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="John Doe" required></form>
```

A few additional things to note:
- You may use aria attributes to further enhance your html (e.g. aria-describedby)
- if you're using HTML5 (which you really should be nowadays), the correct way for specifying a boolean (on/off) attribute is like 'required' instead of 'required="required"', e.g. you already set it to true by using it, and don't have to set any value to it furthermore
- Always think FFF - form follows function - as well as: CSS should be used to control optical appearance and should not need additional html (I know there are cases where you can't circumvent that, but most of the time additional html is not needed, especially no 'div mess')

---

I would suggest kicking bootstrap and using plain media queries (optionally using whatever css-preprocessor you like, like e.g. stylus, sass/scss, less, ...). If you really think you need to use a framework, foundation has always seemed to be a better option.

But in the end it's boiling down to plain html and css, and nobody limits you to only use the stuff provided by the framework - you can always override thinks with your own css rules.

Been doing web dev for about 8 years now together with a team of about 15 people currently, and some of use prefer frameworks while others (me included) stick to plain css (with the addition of whatever preprocessor is the most practical for the project, e.g. node projects work better with stylus while php projects are easier to integrate with sasss). The only situation where I think a framework really helps speed up development is - IMHO - when the project is designed, from the first step, to be built on that specific framework.

As said, this is my personal oppinion, and I hope it helps you to know that it's a valid option to override individual things with custom tailored css rules - if not, feel free to expand on your question and provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [drupal cms](http://wearepropeople.com/) behaviors- If you’re adding JavaScript to your custom module it is very easy and tempting to simply add it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  alert(‘hot dog flavored water’);
});
```

Now this code works perfectly fine but what if your JavaScript needs to be executed on page load and after an AJAX request? Imagine you have a view that uses “Views Infinite Scroll” and you want add a CSS class to every result like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.view-display-id-page .views-row').addClass('fancy-pants');
});
```

This will work for the results that are displayed initially but for all the results that are loaded by Infinite Scroll's AJAX call the class is not added. That’s where Drupal behaviors come in handy.  The behaviors will be executed on every request including AJAX requests, so let's do the equivalent of the code above but this time using this method:

```
Drupal.behaviors.infiniteScrollAddClass = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('.view-display-id-page .views-row').addClass('fancy-pants');
  }
};
```

I admit that was quick - so here are some explanations:

infiniteScrollAddClass: This is your namespace and should be unique. For example, this is typically the name of your module, but it isn't mandatory.
context: This is actually really really cool, on page load the context will contain the entire document and after an AJAX request will have all the newly loaded elements. This way you can treat content that is loaded in via AJAX differently than others.
settings: This contains information passed on to JavaScript via PHP, it is similar to accessing it via Drupal.settings. For further comprehension I recommend this source.
There obviously are cases where some functionality should not be executed on every request. In such a case its great to use jQuery's .once() method. So let's say we want to give all the initially loaded results in our view an additional class, for something like this we would proceed like so:

```
Drupal.behaviors.infiniteScrollAddClass = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // these are the elements loaded in first
    $('.view-display-id-page').once(function(){
      $(this).find('.views-row').addClass('i-was-here-first');
    });

    // everybody
    $('.view-display-id-page .views-row').addClass('fancy-pants');
  }
};
```

This will add the class “i-was-here-first” to all the view results present on page load, everybody else joining in via AJAX will just get the “fancy-pants” class.

So that’s a quick look at Drupal behaviors, if you haven’t used it do use it!

If you are looking for additional theoretical insight into this topic I can recommend these two sources for further reading:

The Drupal JavaScript API (for Drupal 6 but explains it very well and mostly also applies to Drupal 7)
Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can make a website fully responsive,

**About responsive Bootstrap**
Responsive devices
Media queries allow for custom CSS based on a number of conditions—ratios, widths, display type, etc—but usually focuses around `min-width` and `max-width`.

Modify the width of column in our grid
Stack elements instead of float wherever necessary
Resize headings and text to be more appropriate for devices
Use media queries responsibly and only as a start to your mobile audiences. For larger projects, do consider dedicated code bases and not layers of media queries.

**Supported devices**
Bootstrap supports a handful of media queries in a single file to help make your projects more appropriate on different devices and screen resolutions. Here's what's included:

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Read this, http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html will help you out:)

keep in mind that Retina (Apple products screen stuff) does have a specific resolution/pixel-ratio

You could take a look here : http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ they explain and have examples